# Reddit messing up my laptop

Tags: google-chrome, laptop, nvidia-graphics-card

Whenever I am using Reddit in Chrome, my Laptop (Acer Nitro AN515-57 with RTX 3060) starts lagging. The screen starts flashing black and any video that is playing at the moment stops. This doesn't happen on any other site, solely on Reddit and the issue stops whenever I close the Reddit tab. Any ideas about what this might be caused by and how to solve it? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try a different browser. For the odd occasion when I use Reddit, there are not any issues.